# Dimension of the Splitting field

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, splitting-field

I'm working through a Galois Theory book and I'm stuck on the following:

$\left |\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt{3},i:\mathbb{Q})  \right |$. I've (hopefully correctly) that this is a normal field extension but I can't see where to go from here to show what the dimension of this field is.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use Dedekind's Product Theorem. The degree is equal to $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)(\sqrt[3]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})(i):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$, whereas $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$. Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3}, \sqrt{3}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 6$ because both 3 and 2 must divide this dimension, and the dimension can't be more than the product (the products of elements in a basis for each will span $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt{3}) / \mathbb{Q}$). But then when you adjoin $i$, you'll either multiply the dimension by $2$ or leave it alone, the latter happening only if $i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt{3})$, but $i \not\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt{3})$ because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt{3})$ is totally real. So the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{3},\sqrt{3}, i) / \mathbb{Q}$ is 12.